# Symfony 2 Forms and Doctrine Mongo - How to render @Embed and @Hash properties?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, doctrine-odm

I'm totally stuck in combination of Symfony Forms and Doctrine MongoDb and need your help.

I have a User class with @EmbedMany and @Hash:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Project", strategy="set")
     */
    protected $projects;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Hash
     */
    protected $schedule;
}
```

Project class:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

After saving a new record by Doctrine Document Manager, I've got this structure:

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "projects": [
     {
       "_id": ObjectId("50d1c5116146a13948000000"),
       "name": "Project 1"
     },
     {
       "_id": ObjectId("50d069336146a10244000000"),
       "name": "Project 2"
     }
   ],
   "schedule": ["2012-12-01", "2012-12-04"]
}
```

Also there are 2 collections - Projects and Schedules, filled with data.

When I try to edit a User, I want to show a form with 2 checkbox-lists containing data from these collections and selected items the user have.
Like this:

[image: Example]

The question is how to build such form for @Embed and @Hash properties?

I tried different ways:

```
class UserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('schedule', 'collection', array(
            'type' => 'choice',
            'options'  => array(
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
            ),
        ));
        $builder->add('projects', 'document', array(
            'class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Document\Project',
            'property' => 'name',
        ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Document\User');
    }
}
```

or

```
 $builder->add('schedule', 'choice', array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
 ));
 $builder->add('projects', 'collection', array(
        'type' => 'choice',
        'options'  => array(
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
        ),
 ));
```

Some of these failed with error: `Expected argument of type "array", "string" given`. Some produced successful form render, but no selected items in a list.

Maybe I should use custom Data Transformers or manually render these controls...

Answer (score 1):

To use embedded documents, the embedded document must be annotated as EmbeddedDocument, not Document. However, it looks like you actually want to be using ReferenceMany on your annotation of projects in your User Document; it makes no sense to select from a list of embedded documents unless you're say choosing which to delete.

Comment: This is partially true. Documents can behave as EmbeddedDocuments, but not the otherway around. A specific use case where it was required for me was to save specific object snapshot from a generated collection, which expires after some time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the @Hash problem. Considering numeric indexed array, @Collection annotation should be used instead.

```
$builder->add('schedule', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => <your choices list here>,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
));
```

The @EmbedMany problem still actual.